# how to give multiple border color to same css class

Tags: css

I am very new to CSS. 
I have CSS for timeline. I want to multiple BORDER colors. for example red , blue, green
How I can do this.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled timeline  red widget">
  <ul class="list-unstyled timeline  blue widget">
  <ul class="list-unstyled timeline  green widget">



.timeline h2.title:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 3px solid #d2d3d2;  <-- want to override with another class
    border-radius: 14px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}


.timeline .byline {
    padding: .25em 0;
}
```

Check, there is two rounded timeline balls, I want different color for each ball
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `border-image` and `linear-gradients`. For the gradients, we need to add vendor prefixes.

Unfortunately, gradients do not work on border properties. I found that out through trial and error.

Here is a small example.

```css
.multicolored {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
  border-image: -moz-linear-gradieunt(red, green, blue);
  border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
  border-image: -o-linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<ul class='multicolored'>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Mangos</li>
</ul>
```

It's important to keep in mind that gradients are not available in IE9 or earlier.

If you wanted different border edges to have different colors, you would do the following

```
<div class='multicolored'>This is a div</div>

.multicolored {
    border-top: 5px solid red;
    border-right: 5px solid green;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
    border-left: 5px solid gold;
}
```

It's a start. I will work on perfecting it.

Comment: what is wrong with this answer? If you let me know i can fix it

Comment: is there any thing like sub class of timeline class. want to append border within timeline . <ul class="list-unstyled timeline  green widget">

Comment: I took away my down vote, i may have misread the question... although it says 'multiple border colors to same css class'.  I'm still not sure what that means

Comment: thank you. I'm researching linear-gradients on borders. I think that might solve it

Comment: yep that was my initial interpretation, but I'm not sure the question matches the title to be honest

Comment: I have css class called timetime. It has border color, I want to keep timeline as is, I am looking for flexibility if somewhere I want to replace border color .. like override

Comment: Nope. Sorry If I am not clear, but I want to OVERRIDE original timeline border border. I already have one css class called timeline. Please see above in post

Comment: I added an image in post

Comment: This is going to take some time. Please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way I've found to apply multiple border **colors** to an element is by *not* using the `border` rule but by using the `box-shadow` rule on an element; this will give the element the *appearance of having multiple borders of different colors*, even though (as we know, this is not possible with the simple `border` rule).

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4pz24vcn/1/)**

```css
div {
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

.border {
    box-shadow:
    0 0 0 5px red,
    0 0 0 10px yellow,
    0 0 0 15px aqua,
    0 0 0 20px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: Can we write subclass of timeline to override border color. for example .timeline .bred{}  .timeline . bgreen{} ... to override .timeline border color.

Comment: My target is, If I using 10 times this timeline on 10 section on a page then each time I get new border color

Comment: @fresher to **first question** - of course you can - **[look here](https://jsfiddle.net/4pz24vcn/2/)** - for **question two**: I have no idea what that means